# How to resize Polygon In open layer 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I have drawn polygon using

```
new ol.interaction.Draw
```

now I want to resize it.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to scale the polygon relative to its center point? This is not (yet) supported (though there is an open [PR](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3333)). If your question is about modifying a geometry in general, there is a modify interaction (see this [example](http://openlayers.org/en/master/examples/modify-features.html)).

Comment: I already used modify interaction but that is reshaping the polygon...Actually..I just wanna resize polygon in ol3