# how to use open layer 2 OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESIZE constant in open layer 3

Tags: javascript, openlayers, openlayers-3

I want to resize my polygon layer in open layer 3 ,but there is no feature of resize in open layer 3 .

So , Can we use open layer 2 (OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature.RESIZE) constant in open layer 3?. or can anyone tell me procedure to resize vector layer in open layer 3 as [done](http://dev.openlayers.org/sandbox/august/trunk/examples/modify-feature.html) in open layer 2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to resize Polygon In open layer 3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36796179/how-to-resize-polygon-in-open-layer-3)

Comment: thanks ... but i want to know  .. is resize feature deprecated from OL3? or it will include in next release of ol3?

Comment: OpenLayers 2 and 3 are not compatible. It might get included in the future (e.g. see this open [pull-request](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/3333)).